# How to multiple join in cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I want to put join in my query, but I can't get any success, I want to find out the `productname` from the `product` table, if the `product_id` exists in the `productplan` table.

```
 Producttable     
 id name
  1   a
  2   b 

 productplantable
 id product_id
  1   1
  2   2
```

This is my query:

```
$p_products = $this->ProductPlan->find('all',   
                                       array('fields'=> 
                                         array('ProductPlan.product_id',
                                               'Product.name')
                                       )
                                    );
$this->set('p_products',$p_products);
```

Comment: Have you define relation ship between both tables in respective models ?

Comment: i m sure about that there is no problem in relationship, product hava hasmany relationship and product plan have belongsto relation against product

Comment: obiously relationship has been defined

Comment: Try to add `$this->ProductPlan->recursive = 2` just above your find query.

Comment: @Rikesh no dude it's not worked

Comment: Try `$this->ProductPlan->Behaviors->attach('Containable');` above query.

Comment: @Rikesh can u give me a proper exact query, please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24548/discussion-between-rikesh-and-usman-ali)

Answer (score 0):

If your relationship is setup correctly in your ProductPlan model, the following should work.  If not, please provide the source code for your ProductPlan model.

```
$this->ProductPlan->Behaviors->attach('Containable');

$p_products = $this->ProductPlan->find('all', array(
  'fields'  => array('product_id'),
  'contain' => array('Product' => array('fields' => array('name')))  
));
$this->set('p_products',$p_products);
```